# How can i fetch all the coordinates for every row of in javascript ? as i would like to use lat and long to draw marker on map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am following a youtube tutorial, using this [api](https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations) to fetch coordinates only for every location to draw markers using mapbox api.

Can somebody please help kindly how to fetch just lang and lat values for every country to use them to draw markers in mapbox.

```
[0 … 99]
0:
coordinates:
latitude: "33.0"
longitude: "65.0"
__proto__: Object
country: "Afghanistan"
country_code: "AF"
country_population: 29121286
id: 0
last_updated: "2020-04-01T08:09:37.434801Z"
latest:
confirmed: 174
deaths: 4
recovered: 0
__proto__: Object
province: ""
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 1, country: "Albania", country_code: "AL", country_population: 2986952, province: "", …}
2: {id: 2, country: "Algeria", country_code: "DZ", country_population: 34586184, province: "", …}
3: {id: 3, country: "Andorra", country_code: "AD", country_population: 84000, province: "", …}
4: {id: 4, country: "Angola", country_code: "AO", country_population: 13068161, province: "", …}
5: {id: 5, country: "Antigua and Barbuda", country_code: "AG", country_population: 86754, province: "", …}
```

By using this code

```
function updateMap(){
    fetch("https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations")
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(rsp =>{
           console.log(rsp.locations[0].coordinates);
        });
}
```

I can access first location coordinates as its index is [0] but i want to access all the elements of array and then coordinates object inside and its values of coordinates.

Comment: please explain your question. provide just the structure of the array   and how you want to deconstruct it

Answer (score 0):

Since `locations` is an array of objects, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over and refine each object.

For example:

```
function updateMap() {
  fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.locations.map(obj => obj.coordinates))
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciated big time 